# Images not staying in aspect ratio. Can't use background-image: cover

Tags: html, css, image

If what I am trying to do is not possible, please just let me know.

I'm trying to get all of these different size images to remain undistorted. All the images look great except for the ones that have a smaller width than the container of 285px. I'm ok with the images being blurry because I know we are stretching them. I just want all of them to keep their aspect ratios. The ones that are not working are images #2, #3, and #4.

I can't use any JavaScript for this. It needs to be pure css. And I can't use style="background-image:url" because the images are added dynamically and it will make the entire script not work. Which I think means that I can't use background-image:cover.

http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/9/

```
.squaregallerywrap {
width:  285px; 
height: 285px;
}

.squaregallerywrap img {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 286px;
min-width: 286px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
-o-transform:translateX(-50%);
transform:translateX(-50%);
left:50%;
}

li {    
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s all linear;
transition: 0.4s all linear;
}
```

Comment: As far as  I can tell, what you're trying to do cannot be done.  I'll be watching this question to see if there's a non-JS, non-background-cover solution.

Comment: "the images are added dynamically" — could you say more about this? Is the code that loads them on the server or is there an AJAX call made in JavaScript? In either case, you should be able to use both `background-image:url(...)` and `background-size:cover`, with the dynamic code making the appropriate changes to the HTML.

Comment: I would have to change the jqery plugin that I am using in order to make the background-size: cover work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the best you'll get CSS only.

CSS:

```
.squaregallerywrap {
    width: 285px;
    height: 285px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.squaregallerywrap img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all linear;
    transition: 0.4s all linear;
}
```

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/pp74fb7b/12/)

Comment: That almost works. But it ends up making some of the images really large. Like the tiger and koala.

Comment: Does the html have to stay the same? Out of curiosity, why can't you use javascript?

Comment: No, html can be changed. I can't use javascript because what you are seeing is part of a larger plugin.

Comment: Assuming no image will be more than twice as big in one direction as the other, we can limit the stretch by adding a `max-width` & `max-height` of twice the size of the square container. http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/pp74fb7b/13/

Comment: I have been working on this for days and this is the best answer so far. I am going to check this answer as the correct one. The images are still a little too stretched for me so I am first going to try and edit the jquery plugin directly so that I can use background-image:cover. If that doesn't work, this will be the solution I go with. Thanks!

Comment: @kimberlyvoo can you tell what's wrong with this? - http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/14/ as you mentioned the url issue in one of the comments below.

Comment: @sdcr. If I do what you have, it ends up breaking the jquery plugin that I am using. The little thumbnail images when you click on a gallery image don't show up anymore if I do it your way. You can see it here: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

Comment: @kimberlyvoo had a look, it's using either `data-src=` or `img src=` for the popup, if it's the 2nd, you can still keep the inline image there but hide it with css. so you have same image on both background and inline for each item, doable?

Comment: @src. it's the img src that is showing the little thumbnail. I can't hide it because the img src is also showing the actual gallery image. The image that shows before you click on it to show the lightbox.

Comment: @kimberlyvoo there must be special class or id on the popup box, which you can target, so you can adjust the css to make the image to display again.

Comment: @src. Well then I guess that would work then :) I'm not sure I like the idea of hiding all of the images. But if its the only way. I still am going to try and edit the plugin to work with background-image:cover. If that doesn't work, I will either use your solution or the one above from hopkins matt. Seems I have 3 solutions total, so it's a matter of picking which one is the best. Thanks so much for looking into this and providing a unique solution. It's not one that I thought of before.

Comment: @kimberlyvoo as you said "you've been working on it for days", I really want to help out, yep it's just an idea, I can't be sure if it would work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the images are being added dynamically could you not add them this way instead:

```
<div class="squaregallerywrap" style="background:url('http://smartyet.com/assets/trail-blazer/images/gallery/2/1.jpg')">
```

And then then set background-size:cover on .squaregallerywrap

Comment: I tried that last night and it won't work because it ends up breaking url's in a different location.